# split string and set values to class variable in java 8

Tags: java, spring, for-loop, java-8

```
String decodedChecksum="A01046085|T98494055e|1200|2020-05-31T06:12:46.365Z"
String[] splitArray = decodedChecksum.split("|");
/* here i want to set values to getter setter*/
{
sample.setAppNo(A01046085)
sample.setId(T98494055e)
 ..
}
```

Please provide solution to iterate the array and set valuease to varibale

Comment: The question was not just how to split a string based on "|" but also how the resulting array can be processed to invoke different setters based on current index. IMHO, this is low level design problem that should have been answered.

Answer (score 0):

It heavily depends on how your code is structured. If you're 100% sure of the structure of that string, it's as easy as:

```
String decodedChecksum="A01046085|T98494055e|1200|2020-05-31T06:12:46.365Z"
String[] splitArray = decodedChecksum.split("\\|");

sample.setAppNo(splitArray[0]);
sample.setId(splitArray[1]);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `|` because it's a special symbol in regex.

```
String decodedChecksum="A01046085|T98494055e|1200|2020-05-31T06:12:46.365Z";
String[] splitArray = decodedChecksum.split("\\|");

sample.setAppNo(splitArray[0]); // splitArray[0] = A01046085
sample.setId(splitArray[1]);    // splitArray[0] = T98494055e
...
```